# Optimizing and securing robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a couple of doubts / questions / ideas related to *robots.txt*:

1. Can we deny website for all bots except for chosen ones in order to
   tell other bots not to crawl site:

   ```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /

   User-Agent: Googlebot
   User-Agent: bingbot
   User-Agent: Slurp
   Allow: /person/
   Allow: /products/
   ```
2. Can we deny whole site and then just specify list of pages we want
   to allow for indexing like in example above? I do not want to give
   away URLs that I want to exclude from crawling, as this information
   can be used against me.
3. Note that we do not have `Allow: /`, so will
   bot be able to access home page?
4. In example above, will `Allow` be
   applied for all three user agents on the list or `Allow` needs to be
   pasted under each user agent?

   ```
   User-Agent: Googlebot
   Allow: /person/
   Allow: /products/

   User-Agent: bingbot
   Allow: /person/
   Allow: /products/

   User-Agent: Slurp
   Allow: /person/
   Allow: /products/
   ```

Comment: `robots.txt` is completely unrelated to security. You should use proper authentication to make secret parts of your website unaccessible to unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 6):

The *robots.txt* spec says prefix matching is used. This means if you don't want the excluded URLs to be visible in *robots.txt*, you can simply abbreviate them just enough to not match any allowed URLs.

For example, if you want to disallow `/very/secret`, you could simply use:

```
Disallow: /ve
```

In your *robots.txt* file, and as long as you don't have other URLs starting with `/ve`, which you do want to get crawled, this will work as intended.

You may see bots reading *robots.txt* and then try to get `/ve` from your site. Those bots will get a 404, and you'll get a useful signal in your logfile about which bots are trying to find secret stuff through *robots.txt*.

Comment: That me be the standard, but some bots don't follow it.   Notably, the Baidu spider only obeys robots.txt directives that match directories.  `Disallow: /ve` won't prevent it from crawling `/very/secret`.   You would have to use `Disallow: /very`.

Comment: Reference for above pattern matching of the Baiduspider: http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=search&class=499&id=1000565

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Also, unless something is lost in translation, the second example at point 6 on the [FAQs of Baiduspider page](http://help.baidu.com/question?prod_en=master&class=498&id=1000973) seems to suggest that groups are combined?! (In a similar way to what I think the OP is suggesting/querying in the question.)

Comment: Their treatment or `robots.txt` is non-standard in several ways.  That override functionality is not the way that it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the first thing you should realize is that *robots.txt* is a standard, not a security protocol.  Anything on your site that isn't secured *can* be crawled by a crawler/robot.  The only thing *robots.txt* will do is tell well-behaved crawlers (e.g. GoogleBot) what you would like them to ignore.

Second, I'll recommend running any *robots.txt* you come up with against Google's Webmaster Tools, to help you optimize:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4617736

Lastly, on to your specific questions:

1) Pretty sure that the robots spec is like an ACL in that it goes in order.  Put your specified Allow rules before your `Disallow` rules.  I've also never seen multiple `User-Agent` attributes in a row before.  If it works, it might not work for all bots; I'd suggest making a separate entry for each.

2) Yes, but you should specify which ones you allow first, then deny the rest.

3) They have access to everything that's not behind security.   You have told them you don't want them to index your home page if you do that, however.

4) The second version will work; again if the first version works it will likely not work universally.

Comment: 1) The order does not matter. The longest (most specific) path wins. 2) Actually, probably not - at least not "like in example above". 4) Both will work. Although the two `Allow:` directives are superfluous, you could simply have `Allow: /` or `Disallow:` (with no path).

Comment: 3) robots.txt instructs bots what not to _crawl_, it does not necessarily prevent pages from being _indexed_ (if those pages are being linked to). The above code permits "Googlebot", "bingbot" and "Slurp" to crawl _everything_. It blocks all other bots.

Answer (score 3):

First thing: If the knowledge of "private" URLs "can be used against" you, robots.txt is the wrong tool for the job. It would be safe to assume that only a small part of all bots honour your robots.txt rules.

Second thing: Note that `Allow` is not part of the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html). Some bots support it, others not. Those that don’t support `Allow` should simply ignore lines with this field name.

---

This doesn’t make sense:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-Agent: Googlebot
User-Agent: bingbot
User-Agent: Slurp
Allow: /person/
Allow: /products/
```

Every bot follows *one* record only. If there is no `User-agent` match, it uses the `User-agent: *` record as "fallback".

So this snippet means:

- For every bot **not** matching `Googlebot`/`bingbot`/`Slurp`: Everything is disallowed.
- For every bot **matching** `Googlebot`/`bingbot`/`Slurp`: Everyting is allowed.

So there is no need to specify these two `Allow` lines, as *everything* is allowed anyway.

If you want to disallow everything except URLs starting with `person/` and `products/` for the matching bots, you have to repeat the `Disallow` line:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
User-agent: bingbot
User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
Allow: /person/
Allow: /products/
```

---

> Note that we do not have `Allow: /`, so will bot be able to access home page?

Yes, the default is: everything is allowed.

If you want to make this explicit, you can use:

```
User-agent: …
Disallow: 
# this Disallow line means: everything is allowed
```

It’s likely that `Allow: /` would mean the same (but again, `Allow` is not part of the specification, so every bot may implement it differently).

> […] will `Allow` be applied for all three user agents on the list or `Allow` needs to be pasted under each user agent?

It’s correct to have [several `User-agent` lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307057/1591669) in one record.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. There is a lot here. I appreciate your ingenuity but I suspect that you may be putting too much energy into what should be a rather simple effort.

Your first example, of the two is best though either should work the same. However, I question the wisdom of blocking the home page of your site. Without knowing more about your site configuration, I am at a disadvantage.

I am assuming a few things here. That you do have a home page at /. That the bulk of your site is in /persons and /products. That you want to protect some directories that may or may not be linked to by excluding them in the robots.txt file. That these possible links could specify nofollow and noindex. And that links exist from the home page to the restricted ares.

First things first. I have no experience, and I am sure not too many people do, as to what happens if you block your home page in robots.txt. Would the rest of the site be spidered? I doubt it unless you submit a sitemap that is actually read. Sitemaps are not always taken into account especially if after they are read and the site is small. I find that to be too much of a risk. I would not block the home page and I am not sure why you would do this except that the links to the restricted areas are made on the home page.

Second, you have not told anyone other than through the use of noindex or nofollow, according to my assumptions, that the restricted areas are restricted, they are not restricted. I think you are forgetting that an inbound link (backlink) can be made to these areas and without it being restricted, it will eventually be discovered and spidered. This could especially be true using social media. The use of noindex and nofollow is not the same as restricting something in robots.txt.

One thought that must always be considered. The robots.txt is not a security tool. It is designed for honest robots and cannot block accesses otherwise made with malintent. Other tools and tactics must be applied to protect these areas.

The use of noindex and nofollow assumes that your link is not followed. As stated before, it may be that other links are found that point to these areas. Any noindex and nofollow found upon a link is not stored as a restricted area by a spider but rather simply not followed. This means, unless you restrict areas of your site specifically within the robots.txt file, it will likely be found and spidered at some point.

I have found that spiders come (generally) in three primary flavors; honest, scraper, and hacker. The honest bot is obviously nothing to worry about. Scraper bots for the most part do read and follow robots.txt with a rather small minority percentage ignoring robots.txt altogether. Because of these minority spiders, I have rarely found links to my restricted areas if at all. The final bot is a hacker bot likely one of two types, landscaping and script-kiddie. Neither of these will ever follow or read robots.txt nor will they create links.

In other words, it rarely harms anyone to restrict a directory in robots.txt any more than it normally would be. That you are far better off restricting these areas in your robots.txt file. That failing to do so, you have only yourself to blame if the area gets spidered, scraped, and linked to. And finally, that following the traditions of the robots.txt file is far more beneficial than experimenting. The robots.txt is not part of a security scheme except to inform honest bots. If you need to secure areas of your site, you had better find another way.

Comment: "what happens if you block your home page in robots.txt." - if you are referring to `Disallow: /`, then this isn't just blocking the home page, it is blocking the entire site (the `/` is simply a prefix). However, in the OP's example, there is a separate group for "Googlebot", "bingbot" and "Slurp" - so _nothing_ is blocked for these search engines.

Comment: Well not quite. With respect of course. He allowed the sub-directories only which is in effect blocking the home page and who knows what else according to my assumption. Still, he got some good perspective with the answers which is important. Cheers.

Comment: Only one group (the most specific) applies to any one bot. The 3 user agents specified do not see the `Disallow: /` directive that applies to all the _other bots_, except for the 3 specified. The two groups are _not_ combined. The 2 `Allow:` directives in the second group are in fact superfluous and could have simply been written as `Allow: /` or `Disallow:` (with no path) - to follow the original spec. Since the default behaviour is to "Allow".

Comment: Except that an assumption is made that if x robot is allowed here and here then the rest of the site is disallowed. That is how I am reading it.

Comment: Well that is what the OP is asking (at least one way of reading it), but that doesn't make it a correct assumption - it is after all part of the question. (They would need to explicitly state `Disallow: /` in the second group - as well - for that assumption to be correct.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggestions I made some changes.  Let me note that in
addition that we would like not to expose areas which we do not want to
crawl (by disallow /  and then just specifying what we allow), we have
big issue that we have over 500 bots which come in and destroy our
caching system.   We do not care for any bots except for google, bing
and yahoo.
Anyhow based on you suggestions (thank you all for very good inputs),
this is what I came up with:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0
User-Agent: bingbot
User-Agent: Adidxbot
User-Agent: msnbot
User-Agent: msnbot-*
User-Agent: BingPreview
# https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en
User-Agent: Googlebot
User-Agent: Googlebot-News
User-Agent: Googlebot-Image
User-Agent: Googlebot-Video
User-Agent: Googlebot-Mobile
#User-Agent: Mediapartners-Google
#User-Agent: AdsBot-Google
#
http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/mobile/onesearch/onesearchmb/search-69.html
User-Agent: Slurp
User-Agent: YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /person/
Allow: /archive/
Allow: /forkids/

Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml?page=1
Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml?page=2

Crawl-delay: 10
# GMT (8:00pm pst to 4:00am pst)
Visit-time: 0400-1200
```

Let me break down my new thinking here.

1)
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /

Get all bots which cooperate out of our site

2)

```
# http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0
User-Agent: bingbot
User-Agent: Adidxbot
User-Agent: msnbot
User-Agent: msnbot-*
User-Agent: BingPreview
# https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en
User-Agent: Googlebot
User-Agent: Googlebot-News
User-Agent: Googlebot-Image
User-Agent: Googlebot-Video
User-Agent: Googlebot-Mobile
#User-Agent: Mediapartners-Google
#User-Agent: AdsBot-Google
#http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/mobile/onesearch/onesearchmb/search-69.html
User-Agent: Slurp
User-Agent: YahooSeeker/M1A1-R2D2
```

Now that I banned all bots, for bing, google and yahoo bots I want to
make special provisions.  Just for above bots do following:

```
Disallow: /
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /person/
Allow: /archive/
Allow: /forkids/
```

With "Disallow: /" I am disallowing all links from my site, except for these:
/index.php
/person/
/archive/
/forkids/

Allow: /index.php -  I have added because with "Disallow: /" (from what
I understood), I am blocking my home page, which is not what I want to
do.  Therefore I have added "Allow /index.php", which redirects to
homepage (just domainname.com).

I have added these to inform crawlers of sitemap.

```
Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml?page=1
Sitemap: http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml?page=2
```

Next two might not have big impact:
    Crawl-delay: 10
    # GMT (8:00pm pst to 4:00am pst)
    Visit-time: 0400-1200

Google (and others) ignore "Crawl-delay", and google does not recognize
"Visit-time" directive.

Let me add that I have used google webmaster tools to check above rules,
and besides Crawl-delay and Visit-time disregard by google, I got:
1) That sitemap is recognized and loaded (not sure if I need to have
just first line or all 3 are needed).  But this is ok.
2) Google respected first disallow for all bots, and recognized allows
that I specified in it's bot section.
3) Further more it respected disallow: / as well.

The only thing I could not verify is
Allow: /index.php
To see if I am eliminating my home page.